# Phpmyadmin - Character set is wrong

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm going to say this up front.. I'm no wizz kid with phpmyadmin so please ask for any information that I haven't provided.

I have exported a dump of a db online that from what I can tell has a character set of MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8). I then import this into my local xxamp phpmyadmin which takes a lot longer than usual.

It finally succeeds and imports 3636 queries... When importing the character set is set to utf8.

After upload I then go to my Great website to find it full of loads of odd characters for example: šÆM€ˆˆ”4!­J”EE‘Ô¤R‹U-}HiI¤*M*µ

So I'm wondering why I'm getting these odd characters rather than a nice glossy site

I've had to change the port to 81 by the way.

Let me know if there is anything else I can add to be more helpful

Comment: Are the characters in the DB as UTF8? Is the PHP DB connection set up as UTF8? Is the page set as UTF8?

Comment: how do I check the DB connection?

Comment: Open your DB connection script. Look at the linked thread, see the `Data Access:` section.

Comment: ok its set to utf8mb4_unicode_ci is the Server connection collation and the server Charset is UTF-8 Unicode

Comment: That particular string of gibberish does not may to anything I can recognize; do you have any more clues?